# Django admin login only works with superusers created from shell

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user, django-managers, django-shell

i have a custom user using AbstractUser just to add timestamps and a fk to it

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from .managers import CustomUserManager

class SubUser(AbstractUser):
    if settings.DEBUG:
        parent_user_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    else:
        parent_user_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, blank=True)

    # Timestamps
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I read that to encrypt passwords well I must create a manager:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        print(username)
        print(password)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

when i create a superuser from shell:
`u = SubUser.objects.create_superuser(username='asd', password='asdasd')`
the instance creates successfully, the password is encrypted and my login in admin/ with that superuser works
but if i create a normal user:
`u = SubUser.objects.create_user(username='qwe', password='qweqwe')`
the instance creates successfully, the password is encrypted and BUT my login in admin/ DOESNT work

now, also i read that if I use a custom user i should use my manager, in the shell i did:

```
user_manager = CustomUserManager()
new_user = user_manager.create_user(username='qwe', password='qweqwe')
```

and get a error

```
user.save(using=self._db)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

what did i do wrong?
The users record well in the db, I looked directly at the db
I use django 5.0.1 and sqlite3

when i create a superuser from shell:
`u = SubUser.objects.create_superuser(username='asd', password='asdasd')`
the instance creates successfully, the password is encrypted and my login in admin/ with that superuser works
but if i create a normal user:
`u = SubUser.objects.create_user(username='qwe', password='qweqwe')`
the instance creates successfully, the password is encrypted and BUT my login in admin/ DOESNT work

now, also i read that if I use a custom user i should use my manager, in the shell i did:

```
user_manager = CustomUserManager()
new_user = user_manager.create_user(username='qwe', password='qweqwe')
```

and get a error

```
user.save(using=self._db)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

what did i do wrong?, users should be created correctly but they are not
The users record well in the db, I looked directly at the db
I use django 5.0.1 and sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* work with the manager directly, this will *not* work. You use the manager with `SubUser.objects`, that way it will inject the model into the manager. *Not* by using the `CustomUserManager()`: if you construct such manager outside the model, it will not call `.contribute_to_class()` and thus inject the model into the manager.

Furthermore it is *normal* behavior that a user that is *not* staff can not log in in the admin, since you need to be staff for this. You need to set `.is_staff` to `True` for that. So you can create a non-admin user with `.is_staff` set to `True` with:

```
SubUser.objects.create_user(username='qwe', password='qweqwe', is_staff=True)
```